# Problem with simple if else statement when using Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a small and frustrating problem (albeit I think that it is small and stupid probably) and I have been on it for hours, trying different ways, switching variables around, and just doing stuff to see if it will work.

I have an `XMLHttpRequest` object and I have an `API` that returns spells and their effects. However in the `generateSpellBody` function the `if() else()` statement is not executing properly. I keep getting the result `not a spell`, no matter how I change the conditions, trying different methods, I tried `indexOf()` , `json.parse` etc. I keep getting the result of the `else` condition only inside the `test.innerHTML`

```
const spells = 'https://{my-spells-api-and-auth-key}';
const spellBtn = document.querySelector('.spell-btn');
const spellTextBox = document.querySelector('#spell-text');
let test = document.querySelector('.test');

function getJson (url, callback) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.onload = () => {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            let data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            return callback(data);
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}

function generateSpellBody (data) {

     data.map(dat => {
         if (dat.spell === spellTextBox.value) {
            console.log(dat.spell);
            test.innerHTML = dat.spell;
        }
        else {
            test.innerHTML = 'not a spell';
        }

    });

}

spellBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    getJson(spells, generateSpellBody);
});
```

HTML:

```
    <form method='get'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="spell-text" placeholder="Enter spell">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="spell-btn btn btn-default btn-light">Do spell</button>
    </form>

    <div class="test"></div>
```

Part of JSON data returned:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5b74ebd5fb6fc0739646754c",
        "spell": "Aberto",
        "type": "Charm",
        "effect": "opens objects"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b74ecfa3228320021ab622b",
        "spell": "Accio",
        "type": "Charm",
        "effect": "Summons an object",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b74ed2f3228320021ab622c",
        "spell": "Age Line",
        "type": "Enchantment",
        "effect": "Hides things from younger people",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b74ed453228320021ab622d",
        "spell": "Aguamenti",
        "type": "Charm",
        "effect": "shoots water from wand",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: can you post the data returned by the api?

Comment: @Yousaf I edited my question to include a part of the data returned. I do get the correct spell returned if remove the `else` block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, `map` function is not the right function to use here, use `for` loop.

Coming to the issue in your code, when `if` condition evaluates to `false`, `else` block runs and that gives you the output `not a spell`. Your code will find and update the `DOM` correctly if the correct spell is at the last index of the data array otherwise if you have found the correct spell, in the next iteration of the loop, `else` block will run and overwrite the correct spell with `not a spell`.

Either remove the `else` block or break the loop when you have found the correct `spell`.

I would recommend to remove `else` block and set `test.innerHTML` after loop has ended because you don't want to update `DOM` every time `if` condition evaluates to `false`. This approach is shown in the code snippet below.

```js
const spellBtn = document.querySelector('.spell-btn');
const spellTextBox = document.querySelector('#spell-text');
let test = document.querySelector('.test');

const data = [
  {"spell": "Aberto" },
  { "spell": "Accio" },
  { "spell": "Age Line" },
  { "spell": "Aguamenti" }
];

function generateSpellBody(data) {
  let text = 'not a spell';

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].spell === spellTextBox.value) {
      text = data[i].spell;
      break;
    }
  }

  test.innerHTML = text;
}

spellBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  generateSpellBody(data);
});
```

```html
<form method='get'>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="spell-text" placeholder="Enter spell">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="spell-btn btn btn-default btn-light">Do spell</button>
</form>

<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: BTW, why use `XMLHttpRequest` when you can use `fetch` api to make a HTTP request?

Comment: It is my next step. I learnt about `XMLHttpRequest` and then `promises`, now I want to do `fetch`. I feel that I need to learn everything, and not just jump to the best one yet. I am starting with basics, and improve my code from there on

Answer (score 0):

```
 function generateSpellBody (data) {
    var newArray = data.map(dat=>dat.spell ===spellTextBox.value?dat.spell:'not a spell')

   for (let i =0; i < newArray.length; i++){
      test.innerHTML = newArray[i];
   }

 };
```

you can use timeOut fuction inside for loop to see the effect

```
for (let i =0; i < newArray.length; i++){
     setTimeout(function(){ test.innerHTML = newArray[i]; }, 3000);

   }
```

Comment: Can you please explain? Why can't I use a map() and is there a reason why my if else block is not working properly? I would like to know what I did wrong.

Comment: Oh it's my bad!!!  Somehow I forgot to write map, the map is the best option in our case, if you do not want to use map then the combination of reduce and filter will work in these case